# Cordova command run issue (throw in q.js) - Win 10, nodejs 7.1.0

Tags: cordova

nodejs v 7.1.0
npm v 3.10.9

```
C:\Users\Adam>npm install -g cordova
npm WARN deprecated node-uuid@1.4.7: use uuid module instead
C:\Users\Adam\AppData\Roaming\npm\cordova -> C:\Users\Adam\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\bin\cordova

C:\Users\Adam>cordova -v
C:\Users\Adam\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:126
                    throw e;
                    ^

Error: write EINVAL
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
    at WriteStream.Socket._writeGeneric (net.js:715:26)
    at WriteStream.Socket._write (net.js:734:8)
    at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:334:12)
    at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:320:5)
    at WriteStream.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:247:11)
    at WriteStream.Socket.write (net.js:661:40)
    at WriteStream.stream.write (C:\Users\Adam\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\ansi\lib\newlines.js:36:21)
    at MuteStream.ondata (stream.js:31:26)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
```

I'm trying few times install and uninstall and clear cache 
from Windows cmd and nodejs cmd. Not help.

Few days ago installed Native scripts and is working ok.

Maybe Cordova not working with nodejs 7.x?

I'm trying install also with @latest
npm install -g cordova@latest

when uninstalling:

```
C:\Users\Adam>npm uninstall -g cordova
- abbrev@1.0.9 node_modules\cordova\node_modules\abbrev
- acorn@1.2.2 node_modules\cordova\node_modules\acorn
- ansi@0.3.1 node_modules\cordova\node_modules\ansi
- ansi-escapes@1.4.0 node_modules\cordova\node_modules\ansi-escapes
- ansi-regex@2.0.0 node_modules\cordova\node_modules\ansi-regex
- ansi-styles@2.2.1 node_modules\cordova\node_modules\ansi-styles
- [... many others]
- nopt@3.0.1 node_modules\cordova\node_modules\nopt
- update-notifier@0.5.0 node_modules\cordova\node_modules\update-notifier
- cordova@6.4.0 node_modules\cordova
```

Comment: downgrade node to 6.9.1 fix the problem. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a new bug from cordova with some of the Node.js versions.

**Solution**:

> downgrade node to 6.9.1 fix the problem

Answer (score 1):

Seems to work okay with node version 7.2.1